# can I use "new SomeClass(){}" to be a parameter passed into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, parameters, anonymous

I want to invoke a function like `openInfoWindow(SomeClass sc)`, sc as a parameter. 
However,codes like this `openInfoWindow(new SomeClass(){width=1;})` didn't work out.
Is it invalid for a anonymous class to be passed into a function as a parameter in Javascript?

looking forward to your help!!

Comment: Javascript is not a strongly typed language; it is used differently than C#.  For such situations, pass a parameter object. (raw object literal)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is syntactically incorrect, try

```
openInfoWindow(new function(){this.width=1;})
```

Comment: @SLaks is it because of `width=1` where it is not assigned to instance

Comment: @SLaks: Why wouldn't that work? It's an anonymous function being used as a constructor. `this` will be the new object, and the return value (that same object) will be passed as the argument.

Comment: @BlueSkies at first I didn't use `this.width=1;`, I just copied what OP had `width=1;` might be because of that...

Comment: Yes.  Also, this offers no advantage over `{ width: 1 }`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't see the early version. The only advantage would be an intermediate object in the prototype chain. But unlikely that it would be utilized.

Comment: @SLaks yes that is correct.... I thought there might be more in the function... not just the assignment part